# Replacing line in loop php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

What I'm trying to do is take an html form input and check it against an associative array I have setup in a php file.

```
foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($user, $company)) {
        print "*=*=*$key ==> $value <br />";
    }
    else {
        print "$key ==> $value <br />";
    }
}
print "<br />";
```

Right now what its doing is if it finds a match in the keys, it will print out every line either like *=*=*$key ==> $value or like $key ==> $value

What I want to do is have only that line where the match is change. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Can you give an example? Right now you are saying, if exists print this, if not print that. All your $company array-items are expected to show up.

Comment: Yes, I want all of the lines to print, but I want the lines where there are matches to change, the rest stay the same

Comment: Still need an example. Change from what to what? What does it look like when it stays the same? Do you want the page to change without reloading? In that case you should look at jQuery or AJAX.

Comment: here's what it is supposed to look like http://i.imgur.com/buIzZwp.png

Comment: As you can see, you type in some values, and search for them, and the second picture is what it is supposed to return, where the matches are bolded and the ones that are not matches it says they were not found

Comment: Add to your code an example of what $company looks like, and what $user looks like.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to get it to search against the array, but whats happening now is it will only match if I have an exact match of the key or the value. When I try to trim the spaces, nothing seems to be happening, also how would I make it case-insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value of $user is not changed in the loop, it will print out the same thing for every array entry. It appears that your test should be simpler.

Just check the key against the value you want:

```
foreach ($company as $key => $value) {
    if ($user == $key) {
        print "*=*=*$key ==> $value <br />";
    }
    else {
        print "$key ==> $value <br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I was able to get it to search against the array, but whats happening now is it will only match if I have an exact match of the key or the value. When I try to trim the spaces, nothing seems to be happening, also how would I make it case-insensitive?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to make it case insensitive is to force everything to lowercase, e.g. if (strtolower($user) == strtolower($key)) {... As for the trim changing the match, you'd need to look into why there are trailing or leading spaces, as that seems unusual.

Comment: The trailing and leading spaces are part of the assignment, we're supposed to make it so it will trim or remove those spaces if for example the user adds an extra space by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `isset()`:

```
$result = isset($company[$user]) ? $company[$user] : '';
echo $result;
```